# MacBook Pro Recovery (-1005F)

Tags: macos, recovery, internet-recovery

I needed to reinstall macOS, so I deleted my partition and opened the Mac recovery and started downloading Sierra. Unbelievable 6 hours later, the installation was stuck and I turned my MacBook off.

Pressing the power button + <kbd>Command</kbd>command <kbd>R</kbd> gives me this message:

[image]

I tried everything, changing my WiFi authentication type from WEP to WPA/WPA2, all boot shortcuts, resetting SMC/NVRAM.

Pressing power + <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd> shows me the following:

[image]

Clicking the "..." button lets me manually input the WiFi SSID and password, but it hangs forever in the loading indicator.

I don't have another Mac to make a bootable USB stick and reinstall the OS, only Windows.

Comment: That looks like a connectivity issue.  Can you hardwire to the Ethernet to bypass WiFi?

Comment: My Mac doesn't have a Ethernet port, it is a MBP Late 2012 Retina 13, although I can still configure the router using my phone

Comment: Try turning off encryption altogether just to get connected.

Comment: It gives me another error message that I couldn't find anything about: -1005U

Comment: From this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23620636#23620636) - it could be that your Internet connection isn't suitable for the download...6 hours seems to confirm this.  Is there an Apple store near you?

Comment: The 6 hour wait was another WiFi network. The nearest apple store is 500km from me

Comment: Your best bet right now is to find someone else with a Mac to download and create the USB installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to reinstall macOS using a USB stick. Probably the recovery partition data was corrupted and my WiFi network wasn't compatible at all for some reason.